# Google OAuth2 + react-google-login: "redirect_uri_mismatch" when trying to retrieve a refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-oauth

how are you doing?

I'm using `react-google-login` to make the login flow in the frontend.

This is my login button setup:

```js
<GoogleLogin
    accessType="offline"
    clientId={google.client_id}
    cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
    onSuccess={handleLogin}
    onFailure={handleLoginFail}
    prompt="consent"
    responseType="code"
    scope="email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly openid"
    render={(_props) => (
        <Button className="google-login-btn" onClick={_props.onClick}>
            {props.buttonText} <GoogleIcon className="google-icon" height="20px" width="20px" />
        </Button>
    )}>
</GoogleLogin>
```

This is working fine and I'm successfully receiving an `authorization_code` from Google.
The problem is when I try to grab a refresh token for the user.

This is the code I'm using to retrieve the refresh token:

```js
const { client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri } = require('../config').google;

export async function GetRefreshToken(code) {
    try {
        const data = new URLSearchParams({
            code,
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri
        });

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        };

        const response = await axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data, { headers });
        const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.data);

        if (parsedResponse.refresh_token) return parsedResponse;
        else return null;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```json
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

My `redirect_uri` is set as `http://localhost:3000/`, and I have confirmed that it is configured correctly in my Google project.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I finally found a workaround.

Setting the `redirect_uri` as `postmessage` did the trick.

Why? I'm still wondering... But it works!

Comment: This same fix works for `@react-oauth/google` generated authorization code.

Comment: Incredible... What the heck Google? Can't put this in their documentation!?
The issue as I see it is that when you use @react-oauth/google 's useGoogleLogin it uses a popup, which doesn't need a redirect URL, and supplies the result in javascript. but other people had said that using any of the redirect URLs in their google developer console settings for that webapp would work, and that didn't work for me. usegooglelogin redirect_uri_mismatch